# Fortran solving for unknown upper bound of the integral

Tags: fortran

I am trying to implement an algorithm in Fortran that involves solving for the boundary limit of the integral.

For example, I want to find a given the following integral:  integral_(0-t) exp(t) dt = 1/2. which fortran should solve for t.

how would one go about solving this in Fortran?  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific example can be easily solved exactly using logarithms, but I take it that you meant that simply as an illustrative example. If `f(t)` is your integrand and `k` is the target value then you are trying to find a root of the function

```
g(t) = integral_0^t f(u)du - k
```

You could try [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find that root. Newton's method requires that you can evaluate `g(t)` -- which you can by any numerical integration method, and also that you can evaluate its derivative `g'(t)` -- but this is even easier since by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, `g'(t) = f(t)` (assuming `f` is continuous).

Newton's method doesn't always converge and it tends to do better if the seed value is close to the root. You could try a preliminary [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) approach which gets you tolerably close to the root followed by Newton's method to refine it.